# Would not the "phrase-request" tag be more appropriate when a user is not particularly interested in a word?

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag wiki for [phrase-request](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase-request) suggests to use [word-request](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-request) when the OP is interested in a word, or when the OP doesn't care.

In the latter case, would not [phrase-request](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase-request) be more appropriate?

Comment: I...seem to be missing something. To quote directly from the tag wiki: "If you are looking for a word, or don't care, see the "word-request" tag too."  If you *don't care* about what? Is it a joke I'm missing? /is sleepy and confused. Maybe once I actually get the sentence I can contribute to this question in a valuable manner!!

Comment: I guess it means "if you don't care about the answer," meaning "if you don't care if you are given a word, or a phrase."

Comment: Oh, I see!  That makes sense now, thank you. :)  I think it's worded confusingly on the tag wiki, though, and am glad you brought this up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Phrase" has multiple definitions.  In linguistics, a phrase can be a single word long; in common use, however, a phrase is usually two or more words long.  On the other hand, "word" is seldom defined in a way that includes phrases of arbitrary length. Thus, it's possible to make an argument that *technically*, [phrase-request](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase-request) is the better choice for a catch-all.

From a common use point of view, however, *neither* tag sounds inclusive of the other.  I feel that using "phrase" as inclusive of "word" is at best counterintuitive, because many people expect phrases to be two or more words long.

Therefore, I propose the following:

- Use [word-request](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-request) for word requests;
- Use [phrase-request](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase-request) for phrase requests;
- Use *both* tags when the user doesn't care which sort of answer they get.

Comment: I have to admit I don't really like my own answer--I'm not fond of double-tagging like this.  I think it'd probably better to have only a single tag for both.  This is the best I can come up with, within the constraints of keeping both tags.